# Unable to execute command in cron

Tags: cron

I was trying to configure rsync to backup a directory every day with the name of current day.

```
rsync --verbose --stats --compress --recursive /home/alpha/ /var/backups/alpha/`date +"%a"`
```

Above command is working fine and is syncing data in `Mon` directory. But when I copy the same command in **cron** it is not working

```
13 16 * * * rsync --verbose --stats --compress --recursive /home/alpha/ /var/backups/alpha/`date +"%a"`
```

But when I remove **`date +"%a"`** part from **cron** it works.
Why cron is not executing **`date +"%a"`**?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120094/ubuntu-18-04-cron-job-not-running/1120358 this might be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` sign must be escaped with `\`, since it is an alternate way to end a command in `crontab`.

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

So your `crontab` line should look like:

```
13 16 * * * rsync --verbose --stats --compress --recursive /home/alpha/ /var/backups/alpha/`date +"\%a"`
```

Sources:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job
- https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
13 16 * * * bash -c "rsync --verbose --stats --compress --recursive /home/alpha/ /var/backups/alpha/`date +'%a'`"
```