# Ubuntu 18.04 Cron job not running

Tags: server, 18.04, cron

I want to delete files from a folder that is created from another process with the `2019-02-21` format.

```
# Clear every 6 hours, 5 minutes
*/5 */6 * * * find /data/ding/dong/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

**Update**

Actually `$(date` was not working with cronjob. see the answer for solution.

Comment: It is best to call a script from cron. The script in turn can call `date` command and other commands.

Answer (score 1):

Check if cron is running, may be you have it disabled/not installed:

```
leonid@Desktop:~$ /etc/init.d/cron status
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running)
```

And redirect error output of commands to some log file, to check what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks WinEunuuchs2Unix for the hint.

Create an script in your home directory with `chmod +x` executable access I have done `chmod 0755`
Go to `/etc/crontab` and enter the following line

```
*/5 */6 * * * root /home/john/{your script name}.sh >> /var/log/cronErrLog.txt 2>&1
```

and it will run every 6 hours 5 minutes

You can put this into your `{your script name}.sh`

```
find /data/ding/dong/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```