# wsl cron tar backup not working

Tags: bash, backup, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu in WSL on Windows 10.  jamesk is my windows Active Directory username as well as my default username in WSL. I have set up cron as follows:

- Created task in task scheduler (runs on logon as user jamesk, run with highest privileges checked) to do the following two actions:

  - C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe sudo /usr/sbin/service rsyslog start
  - C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe sudo /etc/init.d/cron start
- Added following two lines to visudo:

  - jamesk ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/cron start
  - jamesk ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service rsyslog start
- Added following five lines to root crontab (my IT folks said I should put cron jobs in the root crontab vice my user crontab):

  - 0 14 * * 3 cd /mnt/c/Users/jamesk/Documents/ubuntu_backups/ && /bin/tar -cvpzf backup-$(date +%F)-pre-update.tar.gz --exclude=/backup-$(date +%F)-pre-update.tar.gz --one-file-system /
  - 3 14 * * 3 /usr/bin/apt-get update -y
  - 6 14 * * 3 /usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -y
  - 9 14 * * 3 /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove -y
  - 12 14 * * 3 cd /mnt/c/Users/jamesk/Documents/ubuntu_backups/ && /bin/tar -cvpzf backup-$(date +%F)-post-update.tar.gz --exclude=/backup-$(date +%F)-post-update.tar.gz --one-file-system /

cron is successfully running; I can see in the log files in /var/log/apt that upgrade is run.  But neither of the backup files are created.  So I looked in /var/log/syslog and saw the following error lines:

CRON[230]: (root) CMD ([231] cd /mnt/c/Users/jamesk/Documents/ubuntu_backups/ && /bin/tar -cvpzf backup-$(date +)

CRON[230]: (CRON) error (grandchild #231 failed with exit status 2)

CRON[230]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

CRON[230]: (root) END ([231] cd /mnt/c/Users/jamesk/Documents/ubuntu_backups/ && /bin/tar -cvpzf backup-$(date +)

I've searched for tar exit status 2 and found nothing helpful to tell me what the error might be.  I also tried adding %> term.txt to the end of the line to get any terminal output, but it looks like the command is not even being fully run (i.e. term.txt is not created).  I noticed that the command seems to be cut off in the logs, made me think that the space after date might be an issue.  So I tried putting the filename in quotes with no change, also tried escaping the space with a \ but that didn't change anything either.  I've tried running the command manually outside of cron, both as root and as jamesk, and it works fine in both cases (just need sudo at the start of the command when run as jamesk).

I then thought that it might be a permissions issue (i.e. the task to start cron is run as jamesk and the root crontab is being executed).  So I stopped the cron service within WSL, used sudo su to become root, and started the cron service as root, then changed the time of one of the backup lines to make it run immediately.  Got the same error.  So I'm stumped as to why this is not working in cron but works fine if I type the command manually.  Does anybody have ideas?  I appreciate any help in solving this.

Comment: The percent sign is special in `cron` - see [Unable to execute command in cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829818/unable-to-execute-command-in-cron)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, that was the issue.  Once I escaped the percent sign it works fine in cron.  I'm new to this; I don't see how I can upvote or mark this as the solution.  But this solved the problem.