# Setup a cron job to archive a directory and all its sub-directories including hidden files using tar

Tags: command-line, permissions, backup, cron, tar

I'm trying to setup a cron job to archive/backup `/home/username/.mozilla/` directory and all its sub-directories, including hidden files, using tar. I like to run the job at 12:01 AM every night.

Here's what I have planned so far:

```
crontab -e

1 0 * * * tar -zcf /home/username/Dropbox/Backups/Firefox_Profile_$(date +%b_%d_%Y_"%H-%M").tgz home/username/.mozilla/ && echo "Firefox profile backed up on:" `date` >> /home/username/jobs
```

Though I have not actually setup the cron job yet, when I run this command in terminal:

`tar -zcf /home/username/Dropbox/Backups/Firefox_Profile_$(date +%b_%d_%Y_"%H-%M").tgz home/username/.mozilla/`

it does create a compressed archive, but upon exctraction, it creates a directory `home` > `username` > `.mozilla` and its sub-directories.

What I am looking for is:

(1) upon extraction there would be either `.mozilla` or preferably `mozilla` (removing the dot), and its sub-directories, including hidden files (no `home` or `username` directories).

(2) is `tar -zcf` the best way to get maximum compression.

(3) keep all the file permissions as it is.

(4) do I need to have [user] (which is "username") in this command: `1 0 * * * username tar -zcf`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to escape ```%``` sign with backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my own answer as, though fliegendewurst's answer helped me somewhat, I wasn't able to complete the command to run a cron job. Comments from bac0n and steeldriver help me figure out the rest.

What's working for me:

`crontab -e`

```
1 0 * * * tar -I 'gzip -9' -pcf /home/username/Dropbox/Backups/Firefox_Profile_$(date "+\%b_\%d_\%Y_\%H-\%M").tgz -C /home/username/ .mozilla/ && echo "Firefox profile backed up on:" `date` >> /home/username/jobs
```

Reference for specifying the gzip compression level using `-I` option:
`https://superuser.com/a/1091640`

Note: If Firefox is open/running at the time of running this command, you might get a message that a file was being written.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the `-C` option, like this: `tar -zcC /home/username -f output.tgz .mozilla`
2. [Read this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/514260/how-to-obtain-maximum-compression-with-tar-gz).
3. Use the `-p` option.
4. I do not understand your question.

Comment: The answer to (4) is **no** in a user crontab (including that of the root user, as accessed via `sudo crontab -e`) but **yes** in the system crontab file `/etc/crontab`

Comment: @Jags please also note bac0n's comment above regarding the percent signs - see for example [Unable to execute command in cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829818/unable-to-execute-command-in-cron)

Comment: @Jags he order of options isn't critical but fwiw I would probably write it as `tar -czf /home/username/Dropbox/Backups/Firefox_Profile_$(date "+\%b_\%d_\%Y_\%H-\%M").tgz -C /home/username/ .mozilla/`. Don't forget the leading `/` on `/home`.