# Cron Job Syntax Help

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts, cron, email

I have a cron job on Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS defined to send me an e-mail containing the results of a shell script as follows (*redacted*):

```
# Weekly Fail2Ban Status Report
0 2 * * 7 /home/myuser/bin/fail2ban.sh | mail -s "Weekly Fail2Ban Status Report as of $(date +%F)" -r "Fail2Ban<fail2ban@mydomain.com>" admin@mydomain.com
```

When I run the `fail2ban.sh`, it produces the "correct" output and everything looks great. It's a "simple" script that I got from someone else (*although I admit that I can't decipher everything in it*):

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo >&2 "Error - exited with status $? at line $LINENO:";
         pr -tn $0 | tail -n+$((LINENO - 1)) | head -n7' ERR

if  tty -s ; then
    tput reset
fi

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

execFail2Ban (){
JAILS=`sudo fail2ban-client status | grep "Jail list" | sed -E 's/^[^:]+:[ \t]+//' | sed 's/,//g'`

for JAIL in $JAILS
        do
            sudo fail2ban-client status $JAIL
        done

echo "fail2ban is finished"

}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

execFail2Ban
```

However, the e-mail that I receive doesn't include those results. What I get instead is an e-mail from **Cron `<root@host>`** with the cron job's definition as the subject and the following in the body:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

If I try to manually run the full definition of the job as a command (*with or without `sudo`*) - `$ /home/myuser/bin/fail2ban.sh | mail -s "Weekly Fail2Ban Status Report as of $(date +%F)" -r "Fail2Ban<fail2ban@mydomain.com>" admin@mydomain.com` - I get a whole list of errors/warnings about broken pipes and so forth instead of the expected output that I get when I just run the script (*again, with or without `sudo`*).

If I try to just run the `$ mail -s "Weekly Fail2Ban Status Report as of $(date +%F)" -r "Fail2Ban<fail2ban@mydomain.com>" admin@mydomain.com` part, it prompts me for a `Cc:` and I have to `~x` out of the `mail` command.

I tried adding a cron job to my individual crontab with the same basic definition:

```
* * * * * /home/myuser/bin/fail2ban.sh | mail -s "Weekly Fail2Ban Status Report as of $(date +%F)" -r "Fail2Ban<fail2ban@mydomain.com>" admin@mydomain.com
```

But now it appears to be sending the same "failed" message to `myuser` (*for which I don't currently have a "forwarding" rule set up to deliver it to my SMTP server*).

I'm sure the problem is probably *super* simple, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly is wrong. I tried adding an additional set of parentheses around the `$(date +%F)` part of the subject, but that doesn't seem to have helped either. I had tried to test the basic `mail` stuff before I put this cron job in place and was able to get a simple mail to go through successfully, so I *thought* the syntax there would be correct.

I'm used to writing code in .NET in a Windows environment, so a lot of this is just me trying to learn a new language, but I could use a little assistance with this one. I'm just not sure *where*, exactly, it's expecting this closing parenthesis. Is it in the script itself, the script's output, or the crontab entry? I don't see any unmatched parentheses in any of the three, but it's certainly possible that I could simply be overlooking it.

Comment: I suspect the issue is the unescaped percent sign - see [Unable to execute command in cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829818/unable-to-execute-command-in-cron)

Comment: @steeldriver - Thank you for that. Yes, that has allowed the mail to be successfully sent. I wasn't aware that `%` would end the command, so I'll try to keep that in mind going forward. The e-mail sent from my "personal" cron tab ***still*** doesn't contain the actual output from the script except for the very last line (`fail2ban is finished`), but at least the messages are actually being sent now. I'll wait until the weekly job runs and try to troubleshoot that if it's still having issues.

Comment: You probably want to remove any occurrences of `sudo` inside the script - if you're running it from root's crontab they're superfluous, and if you're running it from an unprivileged crontab, `sudo` won't have a TTY on which to request authentication.

Comment: Ahhh... Well, that makes total sense. LOL. I'm pretty much a complete n00b in the *Nix environment, so all these little tips are just going to make me better. Thanks again! Please post an answer so I can accept it.