# Crontab job that compresses file with timestamp

Tags: command-line, permissions, cron, timestamp

Ubuntu (Oracle VM virtual box)

I got an assignment to write 3 crontab jobs as follows:

1. logger - job that prints the date into /var/log/myDate.log every 30 minutes
2. archiver - job that compressed /var/log/myDate.log using gzip every day at 2:00 am with a timestamp (/var/log/2022_08_03.log.gz)
3. cleaner - job that cleans all gzip files except the 7 recent ones.

This is what I got so far:

```
nevosmic@nevosmic-VirtualBox:~$ crontab -e
#
#
* /30 * * * * date >> /home/nevosmic/myDate.log
0 2 * * * gzip /home/nevosmic/myDate.log
```

This is working fine. Creates the myDate.log file in /home/nevosmic and prints the date every 30 min.Than creates myDate.log.gz in 02:00

The first problem I have is that /var/log/ directory has no permissions to write to other users (Sould I create the crontab job from inside root?)

**UPDATE:**

I did $ sudo crontab -e and it works.
I managed to create and write to the /var/log/myDate.log. But now, even when I try to store the zipped file in another directory : /home/my_userName/2022_08_03.log.gz the gzip is not working..

My command :

```
#
#
*/30 * * * * date >> /var/log/myDate.log
0 2 * * * gzip /var/log/myDate.log > /home/my_userName/$(date+"%y_%m_%d").log.gz
```

It creates a zipped file /var/log/myDate.log.gz ... but this is NOT my intention.( I need it to be in **/home/my_userName/** )

*Any suggestions on how to do task 3?*

Can I do this?:

```
# Every monday at 02:00 rm all files except the 7 most recent
0 2 * * 1 ls -t /home/nevosmic/logim/*.gz | tail -n 7 | xargs rm
```

Comment: Read `man gzip`. Use `gzip <input >output`.

Comment: You can use the `-c`, `--stdout`, or `--to-stdout` option if you want to redirect gzip's output

Comment: and use /etc/crontab .., it lets you set a user.

Comment: ... as well, there is a typo in your time specs (`* /30 * * * *` needs to be `*/30 * * * *`) and also the `%` signs in the `date` command must be escaped - see for example [Unable to execute command in cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829818/unable-to-execute-command-in-cron)

Comment: /usr/gzip -c /var/log/myDate.log > /home/my_userName/$(date +"%y_%m_%d").log.gz is not working as well.

Comment: I guess all is remaining now is the "cleaner job" ... Work on it and show us your attempted solution and we will help.

Comment: Do you think I can use: 0 2 * * 1 ls -t /home/nevosmic/logim/.gz | tail -n 7 | xargs rm ?

Comment: Something like `find /full/path/diractory/ -type f -name "*.gz" -printf '%C@\t%p\n'| sort -nrk1 | awk 'NR > 7 {print $2}' | xargs rm` would be more accurate ... Also you might want to consider using [`logrotate`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/logrotate.8.html)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Thanks to steeldriver,

This command works for me (I needed the '' before any '%') :

```
#
*/30 * * * * date >> /var/log/myDate.log
0 2 * * * gzip -c /var/log/myDate.log > /home/my_userName/$(date +"\%y\%m\%d").log.gz
```

Comment: So it's working now ... Well done.